# How to set dynamic metadata from Firebase 3.0 in angular JS (With Firebase hosting server)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, metadata

I am trying to set metadata from Firebase response but not display while sharing with social media

**index.html Code**

```
<title>{{metatags.title}}</title>
<meta property="og:description" content="{{metatags.description}}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{metatags.keywords}}">
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase","ngRoute","metatags"]).


config(function ($routeProvider) {
firebase.initializeApp(config);
    $routeProvider.when('/b/healthcare', {
       templateUrl : './views/clinic.html',
       controller  : 'SampleCtrl'
   })
   .when('/b/venues', {
       templateUrl : './views/venues.html',
       controller  : 'SampleCtrl'
   })
.when('/', {
       templateUrl : './views/venues.html',
       controller  : 'SampleCtrl'
   })
  });

app.run(function(MetaTags){
     MetaTags.initialize();
});
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseObject", "$firebaseArray", "$routeParams","$rootScope",
  function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $routeParams,$rootScope) {

 $rootScope.metatags = {
    title : "loading",
    description: "aaa",
    keywords:"business,bla2"
  }

   var ref = firebase.database().ref();

   $scope.datadetails = $firebaseObject(ref.child('metatag').child('venue').child('object2'));

   $scope.datadetails.$loaded().then(function(){

   $rootScope.metatags = {
       title : $scope.datadetails.title,
       description:$scope.datadetails.description,
       keywords:$scope.datadetails.image
   }
   });
}

]);
```

but when I try to share with WhatsApp it give me output like below image 
[image]

( **NOTE:**  I am using Firebase Hosting)

Answer (score 0):

You're unwrapping a promise, which means that Angular is no longer aware of the changes you make to `$rootScope` here:

```
$scope.datadetails.$loaded().then(function(){
   $rootScope.metatags = {
       title : $scope.datadetails.title,
       description:$scope.datadetails.description,
       keywords:$scope.datadetails.image
   }
});
```

The best way to solve this is to *not* unwrap the promise and simply tie it to the `$rootScope` too:

```
$rootScope = $scope.datadetails;
```

With this structure, Angular will automatically be notified when the data is read from the Firebase Database *and whenever it is updated*.

If this somehow is not possible (I'm not familiar with the intricacies of `$rootScope.metatags`) you can alternatively tell Angular yourself that there is a change it needs to render:

```
$scope.datadetails.$loaded().then(function(){
  $timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.metatags = {
      title : $scope.datadetails.title,
      description:$scope.datadetails.description,
      keywords:$scope.datadetails.image
    };
  });
});
```

Note that I recommend the first approach, since the second will only work when the data is initially loaded and not when it gets updated afterwards.

A simpler (and better) way to implement the latter, is to not use AngularFire for it and simply listen to the JavaScript SDK `on` method directly:

```
var obj = ref.child('metatag').child('venue').child('object2');
obj.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  $timeout(function() {
    var datadetails = snapshot.val();
    $rootScope.metatags = {
      title : datadetails.title,
      description:datadetails.description,
      keywords:datadetails.image
    }
  });
});
```

This is essentially what AngularFire's `$firebaseObject` does under the hood: it listens for changes to the data with an `on()` listener and then *whenever* the data changes, it informs AngularFire that it needs to update the HTML.

Comment: i tried your given solution but not working while i am share with whatsApp, skype  you can see screenshot here https://i.imgsafe.org/28d6f73ec6.jpg

Comment: Given that my code has no distinction between whatsApp and Skype, I doubt the new problem is related.

Comment: thanks for your reply, here is my source code please review it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hfew6bmcqauwy0/firebase%201.zip?dl=0